# JQuery onclick div hide/show

Tags: jquery, function, onclick

So I'm trying to hide/show 3 different divs. I want to keep track on which one is showing so that I can have a next and back function. Here's what I have so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><cfoutput>#getgame.name# - Introduction</cfoutput></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sigmasim.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".content2").hide();
          $(".content3").hide();
        });

        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;

        function Back(){
        $("#target1 a").click(function(){
         if (i != 0){
             j = i - 1;
             i = i - 1;
              if (j == 0){
                $(".content").show();
                $(".content2").hide();
                $(".content3").hide();
              } else if (j == 1){
                $(".content").hide();
                $(".content2").show();
                $(".content3").hide();
              } else {
                $(".content").show();
                $(".content2").hide();
                $(".content2").hide();
              }
            }
        });
      }

      function Next(){
          $("#target2 a").click(function(){
           if (j != 4){
             j = i + 1;
             i = i + 1;
             if (j == 1){
                $(".content").hide();
                $(".content2").show();
                $(".content3").hide();
              } else if (j == 2){
                $(".content").hide();
                $(".content2").show();
                $(".content3").hide();
              } else if (j == 3){
                $(".content").hide();
                $(".content2").hide();
                $(".content2").show();
              } else {
                $(".content").show();
                $(".content2").hide();
                $(".content2").hide();
              }
            }
          });
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="content">
      <p> hi </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content2">
      <p> hi2 </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content3">
      <p> hi3 </p>
    </div>
    
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; text-align: left; font-size: 24px;" id="target1">
      <a href="#" onclick="javascript:Back();">Back</a>
    </div><div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; text-align: right; font-size: 24px;" id="target2">
      <a href="#" onclick="javascript:Next();">Next</a>
    </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Upon clicking next, the first thing I noticed after adding a console.log to both i and j was that it does not evaluate either on the first click.  If you click next again, it goes through the function twice. It continues to do this even for the back function.

I want to go index through the three "pages" and not give an option to go back if you are on the first page and same for going past the third page.

Thanks, -Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to change your code, so it works dynamically. Meaning, if you add an extra page, you don't need x more line of code.

Therefor change your HTML. Give all the divs the same class and put them in a wrapper div (is needed to define the `eq()` position).

Then you can use the script I post underneath. I commented the function, hope that explains enough about how it works.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.content:not(:first), #back').hide(); /* hide all divs except first, and hide #back button */
    $('.content:first').addClass('active'); /* add a class to the first and active div */
    
    $('#back, #next').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); /* prevent anchor from firing */
        var dir = $(this).prop('id'); /* define the direction */
        var active = $('.content.active'); /* find active item */
        
        var newActive = (dir == 'next') ? active.index() + 1 : active.index() - 1; /* define the new active page */
        
        active.removeClass('active').hide() /* remove active state from the old page and hide it */
        $('.content').eq(newActive).addClass('active').show(); /* add active state to the new page and show it */

        $('#next').toggle( newActive < $('.content').length-1 ); /* hide the next button if there are no next pages */
        $('#back').toggle( newActive > 0 ); /* hide the back button if there are no prev pages */
    });
        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="back">back</a>  <a href="#" id="next">next</a>

<div>
    <div class="content">
        <p> hi </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
        <p> hi2 </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
        <p> hi3 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks all for quick responses. Yea, I'm just starting to learn JQuery and JS. Your code make sense after reading your comments. Very helpful thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see inconsistent output is because of the misuse of Javascript and jQuery

### jQuery Events

The jQuery function `.click()` tells the browser to execute the callback function each time you click on the bound element. In other words you should not be binding the `onclick` attribute in your HTML.

### Javascript Execution

Javascript executes the script top to bottom. Any function declaration it encounters is registered but **NOT** executed.

### Investigating the Crime Scene

So this is what happened.

1. Your HTML page began to load
2. The browser loaded the script before other elements
3. The functions were declared but **Not** executed, therefore the jQuery `click()` wasn't even registered yet
4. The rest of the HTML document was rendered
5. You clicked on <kbd>next</kbd>
6. Nothing happened from your perspective but now for the first time jQuery `click()` was registered
7. You clicked on next again, and two function calls happened

   - Your jQuery `click` was registered again
   - The call back function inside `click` was executed, therefore you see the page move now
8. You click on next again but now three things happen. Everything in Step 7 plus the second registered click is again executed.

### Solution

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/whrqwgrz/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content2").hide();
    $(".content3").hide();


    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;

    $("#target1 a").click(function () {
        if (i != 0) {
            j = i - 1;
            i = i - 1;
            if (j == 0) {
                $(".content").show();
                $(".content2").hide();
                $(".content3").hide();
            } else if (j == 1) {
                $(".content").hide();
                $(".content2").show();
                $(".content3").hide();
            } else {
                $(".content").show();
                $(".content2").hide();
                $(".content3").hide();
            }
        }
    });

    $("#target2 a").click(function () {
        if (j != 2) {
            j = i + 1;
            i = i + 1;
            if (j == 1) {
                $(".content").hide();
                $(".content2").show();
                $(".content3").hide();
            } else if (j == 2) {
                $(".content").hide();
                $(".content2").hide();
                $(".content3").show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <p>hi</p>
</div>
<div class="content2">
    <p>hi2</p>
</div>
<div class="content3">
    <p>hi3</p>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; text-align: left; font-size: 24px;" id="target1"> <a href="#">Back</a>

</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; text-align: right; font-size: 24px;" id="target2"> <a href="#">Next</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The steps helped me understand what I did wrong. I looked at your answer though and when you hit the next button after you get to three and then hit the back button it skips straight to the first div instead of going to div2

Comment: Also just to encourage a familiarity with other simple jQuery methods, I would suggest to take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/whrqwgrz/2/